# Matching elements in an xml file with their declarations in a schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I want to write an application that takes an XML-schema as input and has the following use cases:

1. Instantiate the schema. (i.e. create random XML instances that conform to the schema.)
2. Traverse such an XML instance and change values of the elements and their attributes without violating the schema. (This includes adding/removing elements to/from *sequence*s, replacing elements by other *choice*s, adding/removing optional *attribute*s, etc.)

Basically I need a way of representing both the schema and the XML instance in memory, that would allow me to match elements in the instance with elements in the schema. 
Preferably it should be general enough to handle DTD, XSD, and RELAX NG; however, handling XSD will also suffice.

So my question is: Is there a library that allows me to do just that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dom4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) is a very good java xml library. I don't think any library will do your first use-case out of the box, but it should be relatively easy to implement yourself.

For schema validation they use [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html), which might be enough to do what you want. Never used it directly, though.

Comment: I actually tried using Xerces to represent the schema (as an XSModel); however, I could not find a way to iterate over all of its elements (iteration over global elements is ok, though)

Comment: Also, I only found a way to search for top-level declarations, and I really really want to avoid having to validate the XML instances because it would be simply inefficient - I already know it's valid because I instantiated the schema myself.

Comment: Well, in Dom4J you can address elements in XPath notation and retrieve a list of matched nodes. That should enable you to iterate all elements. Have to admit I haven't used it too extensively, though.